Small signal model from two transistors stage
I'm looking for help to find the equation of Vout of this design. I tried to do small model equivalent circuit and equations using with KVL. But I can't find the way to solve my system of equations, could you help me ?
Thanks




do you need to solve it by KVL? Because circuits like that are better solved stage by stage (if Vout is the voltage on the collector of Q2, you have two direct-coupled EC stages, with an input bootstrap in the first one)... it can be solved (in an approximate way) by inspection. KVL in this kind of circuit is for computer, not humans.
